# Having Trouble Running SambaCry exploit

Tags: python, security, samba, exploit

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWnfN.png)I'm testing the Sambacry Vulnerability with the exploit from Github. My current machine is Kali Linux 2021 and Python version is 2.7.18. I have already installed the Impacket. But I still have this error while I ran the expliot.

What should I do? Do I need newer version of Kali Linux?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: And from [impacket's setup.py file](https://github.com/fortra/impacket/blob/master/setup.py), it is supports python3.6+ versions.